# correlation of several columns need to be calculated

Tags: r, correlation, stat

I'm trying to get the correlation coefficient for corresponding columns of two csv files. I simply use the followings but get errors. consider each csv file has 50 columns

```
      first values <- read.csv("")
      second values <- read.csv("")
       correlation.csv <- cor(x= first values , y=second values, method="spearman)
```

But i get x' must be numeric error!
subset of one csv file

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your 'x' and 'y' can be either `vector` or `matrix`.  Check if that is the case.  Without a reproducible example, it is hard to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read.table` function and all of it's derivatives return a data.frame which is an R list object. The `mapply` function processes lists in "parallel". If the matching columns are in the same order in the two datasets *and* have the same number of rows *and* do not have spaces in their names,  it would be as simple as:

```
 mapply(cor, first_values , second_values)
```

If it's more complicated tahn that, then you need to fill in the missing details with example data by editing the question (not by responding in comments.)

Answer (score -1):

There must be some categorical variable in X.So you can first separate that categorical variable from X and then use X in cor() function.

Comment: that should be column and row names, how couid i drop those?